# Need a cli to check the sha256 hash of a file

Tags: macos, command-line, encryption

To check the sha1 of a file I would use `openssl sha1 <file>` I'm not sure what to use to check the sha256 hash of the file however, what would you recommend?

Answer (score 264, accepted):

You can use

```
openssl dgst -sha256 <file>
```

Tested on LibreSSL 2.6.4 on macOS 10.14 (Mojave).

---

Prior to Mojave you can use `openssl sha -sha256 <file>` or `openssl sha256 <file>`.

To check command line options for the openssl sha command: `openssl sha -help`.

Comment: This is also portable and runs on ubuntu.

Comment: You may need to use `/usr/bin/openssl` explicitly

Comment: "Prior to Mojave" - `openssl sha256 <file>` still works, on MacOS Catalina, as of Nov. 2020.

Answer (score 130):

OS X ships with a [shasum command](https://perldoc.perl.org/shasum).

```
> which shasum
/usr/bin/shasum
```

You can use:

```
> shasum -a 256 <file>
```

More details:

```
> shasum --help
Usage: shasum [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Print or check SHA checksums.
With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

  -a, --algorithm   1 (default), 224, 256, 384, 512, 512224, 512256
  -b, --binary      read in binary mode
  -c, --check       read SHA sums from the FILEs and check them
  -t, --text        read in text mode (default)
  -p, --portable    read in portable mode
                        produces same digest on Windows/Unix/Mac
  -0, --01          read in BITS mode
                        ASCII '0' interpreted as 0-bit,
                        ASCII '1' interpreted as 1-bit,
                        all other characters ignored

The following two options are useful only when verifying checksums:
  -s, --status      don't output anything, status code shows success
  -w, --warn        warn about improperly formatted checksum lines

  -h, --help        display this help and exit
  -v, --version     output version information and exit

When verifying SHA-512/224 or SHA-512/256 checksums, indicate the
algorithm explicitly using the -a option, e.g.

  shasum -a 512224 -c checksumfile

The sums are computed as described in FIPS-180-4.  When checking, the
input should be a former output of this program.  The default mode is to
print a line with checksum, a character indicating type (`*' for binary,
` ' for text, `?' for portable, `^' for BITS), and name for each FILE.

Report shasum bugs to mshelor@cpan.org
```

Comment: Hmm I don't seem to have it on osx 10.11.3. `which shashum` outputs nothing

Comment: @erikvold You know what? I bet I got with the Xcode Command Line tools. Argh. I really wish Apple wouldn't pollute `/usr/bin` with optional stuff. I'll have to verify this is the case later today. Will update answer if it indeed came from the XCL install.

Comment: `shasum` returns a different hash than `openssl sha -sha256 <file>`(with the latter being the correct hash). Any idea why?

Comment: @ws6079 `shasum` is a perl script, uses `Digest::SHA` to compute the hash value. For the same file I get the exact same SHA using either `shasum` or `openssl` for a `SHA-256` hash computation. See: https://gist.github.com/ianchesal/82a064b8971eb5e717ce84f3ded6dbfd

Comment: shahsum is working great for me today.

Answer (score 14):

To clarify [@John's useful answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/322148/20728) - which allows you to compare a given hash with its file in one command:

Enter `shasum -a 256 -c <<<`,
followed by an optional space,
followed by a single tick (`'`),
followed by the hash to compare,
followed by a space,
*followed by a mode character, based on how the initial hash was generated:*

- *nothing*, if the hash was created with `-t` or no option (text mode, which is the default)
- *asterisk* (`*`), if the hash was created with `-b` (binary mode)
- *question mark* (`?`), if the hash was created with `-p` (portable mode)
- *caret* (`^`), if the hash was created with `-0` (bits mode)

followed by the path to the file,
followed by a closing single tick (`'`).

Like the following breakdown, with delineating parens around the hash and filepath parts, and square brackets around the optional "mode character" part. (*Don't include the parens or brackets in real life - they're just here to make the parts easy to see!*)

```
shasum -a 256 -c <<< '(hashToCompare) [mode character](filepath)'
```

**Broken down**:

The actual *shasum* command is `shasum -a 256 -c`

- `-a 256` tells `shasum` to use *sha256*.
- `-c` tells `shasum` to "check" the provided input.

The `<<<` is a Unix/Linux special character set, called a "redirection" operator. It's for feeding something into a prior command. By using it, we're saying we're going to provide a string of information for the `shasum` command to use as input.

The string of input information must have opening and closing single ticks, such as `'some string here'`, or in this case, the hash, mode character, and filepath to be checked.

- The *hash* part inside the string doesn't need anything special - but it must be followed by a space.
- The *mode character* part can be nothing, an asterisk (`*`), a question mark (`?`), or a caret (`^`). This tells `shasum` the mode with which the hash was generated. *(Note: no character at all, representing text mode, is `shasum`'s default.)*
- The *filepath* part, is the actual path to the file to be checked.

---

So, here's a real-life example checking a particular [MAMP download](https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/) file against it's purported *SHA-256* value. The `*` mode character was required for this check to work:

```
shasum -a 256 -c <<< 'f05ede012b8a5d0e7c9cf17fee0fa1eb5cd8131f3c703ed14ea347f25be11a28 *MAMP_MAMP_PRO_5.2.pkg'
```

**Note:** the result of this command (for my example file) is either -

OK:

> MAMP_MAMP_PRO_5.2.pkg: OK

or

FAILED:

> MAMP_MAMP_PRO_5.2.pkg: FAILED
> shasum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match

---

---

*Update*: I recently had to do something similar, but with a file containing the hash value/filename string. Here is an alternative for that situation:

```
cat <text-file-containing-string> | shasum -a <shasum-value> -c
```

For example:

```
cat qemu-w64-setup-20230822.sha512 | shasum -a 512 -c
```

Comment: For me this works without the asterisk before the filename (as well as with the asterisk).

Comment: `shasum -c <<< '7cb77378a0749f2a9b7e09ea62ffb13febf3759f  *sample.txt'` returns the message `*sample.txt: FAILED open or read`. Without the asterisk, `sample.txt: OK`. I haven't been able to find the basis of the asterisk's use elsewhere yet. Could you clarify?

Comment: Does the presence of the asterisk indicate that the checksum used as input in the example was generated in binary mode ( with `--binary` option)? From the man page:  "When checking, the input should be a former output of this program.  The default mode is to print a line with checksum, a character indicating type (`*` for binary, ` ` for text, `U` for UNIVERSAL, `^` for BITS,`?` for portable), and name for each FILE." So, the characters between the checksum and filename depend on the mode set when the checksum was created?

Comment: @SoFarther: yes, you're right. After some experimentation to prove that idea, I have updated my post to clarify the "mode" aspect.

Comment: So clarify, whether you need an asterisk (or mode character other than default) correlates to the file. Text files can omit the character because the default mode is text. Leaving it out for an ISO will error "shasum: standard input: no properly formatted SHA checksum lines found". Binary file, so the asterisk (binary mode) will be needed.

Answer (score 12):

I would use this command.

```
shasum -a 256 -c <<<'_paste hash to compare here_ *_path to file goes here_'
```

Example:

```
shasum -a 256 -c <<< '0d2ea6de4f2cbd960abb6a6e020bf6637423c07242512596691960fcfae67206 */Users/USERNAME/Downloads/someprogram.dmg'
```